# Gradle transforms https maven repository to http 443 request

Tags: maven, gradle, https, repository

My build.gradle is configured as:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://<myrepo>/repo"
    }
}
```

However,

```
$ gradle build --debug
```

gives me:

```
[...]
12:01:58.487 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyLoggingAdaper] setting 'https.proxyHost' to '<myrepo>'
[...]
12:01:59.070 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper] Performing HTTP GET: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xbib/archive/maven-metadata.xml
12:01:59.316 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] CookieSpec selected: default
12:01:59.324 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
12:01:59.325 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection request: [route: {tls}->http://<myrepo>:443->https://repo1.maven.org:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
12:01:59.336 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {tls}->http://<myrepo>:443->https://repo1.maven.org:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
12:01:59.337 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Opening connection {tls}->http://<myrepo>:443->https://repo1.maven.org:443
12:01:59.340 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to <myrepo>/<reposerverIP>:443
12:01:59.342 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connection established <localIP>:49298<-><reposerverIP>:443
12:01:59.346 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser] Garbage in response:
[...]
12:01:59.347 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] http-outgoing-0: Close connection
12:01:59.347 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
12:01:59.348 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Connection discarded
12:01:59.348 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] http-outgoing-0: Close connection
[...]
```

...though I don't know, why Gradle feels motivated to transform "https" configuration into "http: ... :443". Anyone having a configuration idea?

Comment: I've tried to establish a basic javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection from my client to the repo server - and that works. So, the problem does not seem to be on the Java side, but merely Gradle itself or even a misconfiguration between Gradle and Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wasn't able to find the configuration error itself, I am happy to have the problem solved by simply

1. uninstalling Gradle completely
2. restarting Ubuntu and
3. installing Gradle 2.14 again.